# Setting a UITextField from a cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a simple TableView, when the cell is selected I want that the content is passed to several fields in a detail view so that they can be changed and saved again in the table.

My code has no issues, no errors and, when I debug, sets all variables perfectly, but my field remains empty. I tried with arrays, I tried with strings, no cure.

I 'm making my first steps with Objective-C coming from Java can anybody hep please?

Here is my code:

In my TableViewController.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (!cell){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

SNMGps *selectedCell = [arrayOfCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%d - '%@ - '%@'- '%@'- '%@'", selectedCell.gpsID, selectedCell.name,selectedCell.userName,selectedCell.psw, selectedCell.notes);

SNMAddViewController *field = [[SNMAddViewController alloc]init];


//[field setGpsID1:selectedCell.gpsID];
[field setName1:selectedCell.name];
[field setUserName1:selectedCell.userName];
[field setPsw1:selectedCell.psw];
[field setNotes1:selectedCell.notes];

[field setFields];
}
```

The NSLOG shows perfect data.

In my DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "SNMGps.h"

@interface SNMAddViewController : UIViewController
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *name1;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *userName1;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *psw1;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *notes1;
//@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString *gpsID1;




@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userNameText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *pswText;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *notesText;




- (IBAction)saveEntry:(id)sender;
- (void) setFields;
@end
```

In my DetailViewController.m

```
#import "SNMAddViewController.h"


@interface SNMAddViewController ()

@end

@implementation SNMAddViewController
//@synthesize nameText, userNameText, pswText, notesText, g;

NSMutableArray *arrayOfCell;
NSString *dbPathString;
sqlite3 *gpsDB;

@synthesize name1, userName1, psw1, notes1;
@synthesize nameText, userNameText, pswText, notesText;

- (void) setFields
{

nameText.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name1];
userNameText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userName1];
pswText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",psw1];
notesText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",notes1];
}
```

When I debug the variables name1, userName1 etc. are set to the proper data but the fields nameText.text remains nil.

Comment: are you mapping your UITextField with XIB propperly....? I think you forgot this thing.

Comment: It appears you have allocated the SNMAddViewController view. But where is the navigation logic within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?

Comment: @Renjith I'm nor sure what you mean with " But where is the navigation logic within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:?" The allocation of the SNMAddViewController is in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I assumed when you are allocating a new instance of SNMAddViewController you are missing something like this [self.navigationController pushViewController:field];

Comment: can u please tell me one thing that how you able to see the textfield of the SNMAddViewController if you cant navigate means to go that view on select of tableviewcell.. @Renjith is right

Comment: Or is this detail view controller already on screen(I mean have you already instantiated this like somewhere in the appdelegate)

Comment: @Renjith Now I see what you both mean. I have a segue in the storyboard that points to the detailView. I assumed that if I put the setFields-method in the viewDidLoad it would work. But as said, I am a real beginner and I'm messing things up. Thank you both for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then set the variable just pass the arguement in the method and then assign it as follows

so in DetailViewController.h file change your setFields Metthod as follows:

```
- (void) setFields:(NSString *)name :(NSString *)userName :(NSString *)psw :(NSString *)notes;
```

and in your DetailViewController.m file change the method with as follows

```
- (void) setFields:(NSString *)name1 :(NSString *)userName1 :(NSString *)psw1 :(NSString *)notes1
{

    nameText.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name1];
    userNameText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",userName1];
    pswText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",psw1];
    notesText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",notes1];
}
```

and from TableViewController.m  just call it with

```
[field setFields:selectedCell.name :selectedCell.userName :selectedCell.psw :selectedCell.notes];
```

try this and let me know if its helpful or not.

```
NOTE:
Most important thing is that you never navigate to the SNMAddViewController.. so please navigate to it as per your need
```

Comment: Thank you Bhavik, but sad enough the result is the same, no data in fields.

Comment: How can be data in the field because u never navigate to that view that show you the field.